# Angular jasmine SpyOn service call that throws an error makes the test fail

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I want to test the following method from my component:

```js
  mymethod() {
    this.myservice.dostuff().subscribe((data: any) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.passed= true

    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
      this.passed= false

    })
  }
```

and this is the test I wrote:

```js
  it('if error thrown', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(myservice, "dostuff").and.throwError("error");
    fixture.detectChanges()
    component.mymethod()
    tick(1)
    expect(myservice.dostuff).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(myservice.dostuff).toThrowError("error");
    expect(component.passed).toBe(false);
    flush()
  }));
```

but I must be missing something cause when I run the test, it fails with the following message:
MyComponent On failed login
Error: error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [throwError](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError) to mock what happens when your service encounters an exception. This will trigger your expected error callback.

Your service is expected to return an observable. As you have currently written, the service isn't returning anything - it's just throwing an exception. By using `throwError` and `returnValue` you return an observable that immediately throws, which triggers the expected callback.

```
spyOn(myservice, 'dostuff').and.returnValue(throwError('someError'));
```

Comment: Ok, this goes a step further but still i get the following error message: "Expected function to throw an Error."

Comment: That line that asserts the service throws an exception is incorrect. Your service isn't throwing an exception. It's returning an observable that emits an error.

Comment: Thank you, got it now.